# Spark flat map function is throwing "OutOfMemory"

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-spark-sql

I have below implementation in MapReduce and it is working fine, Now I am trying to port this to Spark by using FlatMapFunction, but this function throws out of memory error.
MapReduce:

```
    String[] hexList = input.toString().split(",");
    int numHex = (int) Math.pow(9, lLevel_From_config - hLevel_From_config);
    for (String hex : hexList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numHex; i++) {
            context.write(m_mapKey, generateHexagon(hex, i));
        }
    }

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.HashMap.createEntry(HashMap.java:897)
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:884)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:505)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217)
    at com.pb.hadoop.spark.hexgen.function.HexGenMapFunction.call(HexGenMapFunction.java:56)
    at com.pb.hadoop.spark.hexgen.function.HexGenMapFunction.call(HexGenMapFunction.java:21)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:129)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1197)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1197)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1197)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1205)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1185)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Spark implementation:

```
@Override
public Iterable<Tuple3<String, Integer, Integer>> call(Tuple2<Text, IntWritable> tuple) throws Exception {
 String key = tuple._1.toString();  
 String[] hexList = key.split(",");
 int numHex =  tuple._2.get();
 Set<Tuple3<String, Integer, Integer>> hegagons = new HashSet<>();
    for (String hex : hexList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numHex; i++) {
            hegagons.add(generateHexagon(hex, i)); //this is line 56
        }
    }
    return hegagons;
```

Comment: can you post full error message?

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, here is the stack trace ...

Comment: could you please increase the memory size in spark-default.conf file eg  spark.driver.memory 5g in $SPARK_HOME/conf folder

Comment: also add spark.driver.extraJavaOptions    -XX:MaxPermSize=6G -XX:+UseG1GC

Comment: Yes it will work after increasing the memory, but the problem is MapReduce works without increasing the memory.  I am trying to fix it without increasing the memory.  This is throwing OOM for a small value, so it will not work with large input.

Comment: @Ajeet - how large is your input now?, from line 56 in your spark code `hegagons.add(generateHexagon(hex, i));` , I assume you are doing a regular java operation something like adding the values in a `hegagons` list object which will be still a burden for JVM if your file size not too large but at-least reasonably  large enough to fill the memory. is `hegagons` object is in global scope of your spark code?

Comment: @Andy - Size of input is not a problem, i tried it after reduce it to kb.  Hexagon is just a simple string, this is also not be a problem. But the value of numHex is big - can go up to 5 million, that is the problem area, it works for small values of numHex but fails with large value. No hexagon is not in global scope. I updated Spark implementation to give it more clear picture. I cant provide complete implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to implement it in Spark. Yes it looks like a workaround to me, because i feel that this is not the best approach to implement it.

**Step 1** : Create an RDD with given number of partitions.

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0; i< numOfPartitions; i++){
    ids.add(i);
}

JavaRDD<Integer> seqRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(ids, numOfPartitions);
```

**Step 2** : Get rows per partitions:

```
int rowsPerPartition = numHex/numOfPartitions + 1;
```

**Step 3**: Now expend these RDDs to create numOfHex RDDs. I am using another parameter maxRowsPerPartition to avoid "OutOfMemory" in PartitionMapFunction.

```
JavaRDD<Integer> numRDD = null;
if(rowsPerPartition > maxRowsPerPartition){
    numRDD = seqRDD.mapPartitions(new PartitionMapFunction(maxRowsPerPartition));               
    rowsPerPartition = rowsPerPartition/maxRowsPerPartition + 1;
    numRDD = numRDD.flatMap(new PartitionFlatMapFunction(rowsPerPartition, numHex));
} else {
    numRDD = hexIdRDD.mapPartitions(new PartitionMapFunction(rowsPerPartition));
}
```

**Step 4**: Apply generateHexagon(hex, hexId) on each RDD with  map transformation to tranasform integer RDD to hexagon RDD.

```
String hex =  HexgenUtilities.getHexgenKey(sparkConfig);
Broadcast<String> broadcastedHex =   javaSparkContext.broadcast(hex);
JavaRDD<Hexagon> hexStringRDD = numRDD.flatMap(new HexGenMapFunction(broadcastedHex, lLevel));
```

This is performing well for me in comparison of MapReduce's implementation. Any suggestion or better approach will be appreciable.
Thanks